# Show that the equilateral triangle has the minimum perimeter between all the triangles with fixed area. (Lagrange Multipliers)

Tags: analysis

As title says I have to show that the equilateral triangle has the minimum perimeter between all the triangles with fixed area.

It's an homework that should revolve around the Lagrange multipliers. I kinda found a way but it looks like a lot of work:
Fix $A$ the area. Heron's formula states that $A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ or $8A^2=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)$ and I have to minimize $f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$ using the Lagrangian multipliers on the differential manifold determined by $\{h=0\}$ where $h(a,b,c)=(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)-8A^2$.

The only thing to do is then imposing the condition $\nabla f(a,b,c) = \lambda \nabla h(a, b, c)$

This should work however it turns out to be quite messy because of the big products in $h$. Is there a simpler way, that still involves Lagrangian multipliers?

Comment: What if you use $A = \frac{bh}{2}$ and express the side lengths in terms of $b$ and $h$ instead?

Comment: @CheeHan I think at least one more parameter is necessary, maybe one side length or an angle. This would involve trigonometry. Does this actually make it simpler?

Comment: If you write $b = x + y$, together with the height $h$, then the remaining two side lengths are just functions of $x, y, h$. I'm not sure if it's simpler, but you could try it out?

Comment: @CheeHan The problem I'm facing with this approach is that acute angled triangles and obtuse ones behave quite differently because in the first case I would say $b=x+y$ in the second one $b=x$

Comment: But every triangle has at least two acute angles so we could always choose $b$ to be the length of the side "joining" the two acute angles?

Comment: Suggestion: use $s,a,b$ as your three independent variables instead of $a,b,c$. Then $f(s,a,b) = 2s$ and $8A^2 = s(s - a)(s-b)(a+b-s)$. And $$\nabla h = (s - a)(s-b)(a+b-s)\nabla s + s(s-b)(a+b-s)\nabla(s -a) +s(s - a)(a+b-s)\nabla(s-b) + s(s - a)(s-b)\nabla(a + b - s)$$ might be a more useful way to express the other side.

Answer (score 0):

The main claim . . .

**Claim $(1)$:**$\;$Of all triangles with area $k=\sqrt{3}/9$, the minimum possible semi-perimeter is $s=1$ which occurs if and only if the triangle is equilateral.

We first prove the following related claim . . .

**Claim $(2)$:**$\;$Of all triangles with semi-perimeter $s=1$, the maximum possible area is $k=\sqrt{3}/9$, which occurs if and only if the triangle is equilateral.

Proof of claim $(2)$ . . .

Let $T$ be the set of triples $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with $0\le a,b,c\le 1$ such that $a+b+c=2$.

Then $T$ is the set of triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a,b,c$ are the side lengths of a (possibly degenerate) triangle with semi-perimeter $s=1$.

For $(a,b,c)\in T$, define
\begin{align*}
f(a,b,c)&=(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\\[4pt]
g(a,b,c)&=a+b+c\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Then for the corresponding triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$, we have $g(a,b,c)=2s=2$,, and, by Heron's formula, we have $f(a,b,c)=k^2$.

Noting that $T$ is closed and bounded, hence compact, it follows that $f$ achieves a maximum value.

Note that on the boundary of $T$ we have $f=0$, and in the interior of $T$ we have $f > 0$, hence the maximum value of $f$ is achieved in the interior of $T$.

A triangle with side lengths $a,b,c$ with $(a,b,c)\in T$ maximizes $k$ if and only if it maximizes $k^2$, hence it suffices to consider the problem of maximizing $f(a,b,c)$ subject to the constraint $g(a,b,c)=2$.

Noting that
\begin{align*}
\nabla f &= \langle{-(1-b)(1-c),-(1-a)(1-c),-(1-a)(1-b)}\rangle\\[4pt]
\nabla g &= \langle{1,1,1}\rangle\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
the method of Lagrange multipliers yields
\begin{align*}
-(1-b)(1-c)&=\lambda\qquad(\text{eq}1)\\[4pt]
-(1-a)(1-c)&=\lambda\qquad(\text{eq}2)\\[4pt]
-(1-a)(1-b)&=\lambda\qquad(\text{eq}3)\\[4pt]
a+b+c&=2\qquad(\text{eq}4)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

As previously noted, $(a,b,c)$ must reside in the interior of $T$, hence $a,b,c < 1$.

Then from equations $(\text{eq}1),(\text{eq}2)$ we get
\begin{align*}
&-(1-b)(1-c)=-(1-a)(1-c)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-b=1-a\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a=b\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and from equations $(\text{eq}2),(\text{eq}3)$ we get
\begin{align*}
&-(1-a)(1-c)=-(1-a)(1-b)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&1-c=1-b\\[4pt]
\implies\;&b=c\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus we have $a=b=c$, so the triangle is equilateral.

Then from $(\text{eq}4)$, we get
$
(a,b,c)
=
\Bigl(
{\large{\frac{2}{3}}},
{\large{\frac{2}{3}}},
{\large{\frac{2}{3}}}
\Bigr)
$,
and from that we get $k=\sqrt{3}/9$.

This completes the proof of claim $(2)$.

Returning to the proof of claim $(1)$, if there is a triangle with area equal to
$\sqrt{3}/9$ and semi-perimeter less than $1$, then we could scale that triangle by an appropriate scale factor to get a triangle with semi-perimeter equal to $1$ and area greater than $\sqrt{3}/9$, contrary to claim $(2)$.

As part of the proof of claim $(2)$, we showed that any triangle with semi-perimeter equal to $1$ has area less than or equal to $\sqrt{3}/9$, with equality if and only if the triangle is equilateral with side length ${\large{\frac{2}{3}}}$.

It follows that any triangle with area equal to $\sqrt{3}/9$ has semi-perimeter greater than or equal to $1$, with equality if and only if the triangle is equilateral with side length ${\large{\frac{2}{3}}}$.

This completes the proof of claim $(1)$.